# Передача данных в Unity3d между двумя устройствами без сервера

Tags: c#, unity3d

Два компьютера подключены к одной локальной сети по Wi-Fi. Нужно передать строку с одного ПК на другой посредством встроенных средств Unity. Какие встроенные классы или Assets посоветуете?

Answer (score 1):

Изучай стандартные возможности [Network Discovery](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkDiscovery.html)

Формально, тебе нужно сделать один девайс сервером, а вторым девайсом к нему подключится как клиенту. А потом настроить обмен данными между ними.